# How to launch PuppeteerSharp on server ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS? System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): Permission denied

Tags: .net, ubuntu, puppeteer, ubuntu-18.04, puppeteer-sharp

The program works on Windows well.
I published it in .Net Core mode on Windows.
But I get that error on Ubuntu:

`Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): Permission denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at PuppeteerSharp.ChromiumProcess.State.StartingState.StartCoreAsync(ChromiumProcess p)
   at PuppeteerSharp.Launcher.LaunchAsync(LaunchOptions options)
   at PuppeteerSharp.Launcher.LaunchAsync(LaunchOptions options)
   at WebScraping.Authorization.GetCookieByAuthorizationAsync(String[] args, String pathToCookieFile) in C:\Users\Serega\Desktop\dz4all\Homework\WebScraping\Authorization.cs:line 22
   at WebScraping.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Serega\Desktop\dz4all\Homework\WebScraping\Program.cs:line 41
   at WebScraping.Program.<Main>(String[] args)`

I can suppose that Visual Studio has published the project for Windows systems only.
My Ubuntu is terminal only.
I have set the "--no-sandbox" and headless-mode at settings of launching of PuppeteerSharp and run the program under the root user on ubuntu.
Consequently, has the dotnet all root privilegies?
All libraries are the latest version.
I have searched in the Internet but I could not find any solution.

Comment: Did you go over the troubleshooting guide and come at a certain point? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: @LexLi, Hello! Yes, I did over the troubleshooting guide. My dependencies are installed. But sections "Chrome headless doesn't launch on UNIX" and "Setting Up Chrome Linux Sandbox" did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that problem. My work directory is `/root/ServerLinux`
I wrote that command: `sudo chmod -R 777 ServerLinux` at `/root`. And all works!